# Is there a way to create ExtJS pure button without a default div container?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm using ExtJS 4, and I'm trying to create a button inside a Panel

```
Ext.define('DL.view.MyPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

    title: 'Login',

    initComponent: function () {
        this.items = [
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: "Login",
                tooltip: "login",
                cls: 'btn-primary'
            }]
    }
});
```

here I use 'btn-primary' to style the button.
But in the generated HTML, the code is as below

[image]

you can see that the class 'btn-primary' is added in its container, a div, not the button itself, which is not what I wanted, and this way, the class won't affect the button.

So is there a way to generate a button whose class is set on the button itself? Or is there a way to generate a *PURE* button without a container? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Normally, you would just change your CSS from `button.btn-primary` to `.btn-primary button`...

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no, not without modifying parts of the framework. The best way to work around it would be to expand the selector:

`.btn-primary .x-btn-inner {}`

Comment: I can't modify the css file, because it's in a library

Answer (score 1):

there is a way to create a pure button

```
{
    xtype: 'component',
    baseCls: 'btn-primary',
    autoEl: {
        tag: 'button',
        href: '#',
        html: 'hello'
    }
}
```

but in this way, it will be a *component* in ExtJS, not a *button*, so maybe it will lost some **button** features that ExtJS gives.